# vue,js fill form from another vue file

Tags: vue.js

I have one file called Main.vue and inside it I have imported others 2 vue files(Table.vue and Form.vue). one table and one form displayed in two different tabs.
What I am trying to achieve is:

If I press the edit button in one row of the table I would like to fill the form with the row data.

What I do is:

1)press edit button to retrieve data from row

2)call a function inside Table.vue - editData()

3)Inside editData() I call another function inside Form.vue - editRecord(modelEdit) where I pass the data of the row

Pressing the edit button I call a function inside Table.vue, this method call another method inside Form.vue passing the data.

This is the method inside Table.vue:

```
editData(){
      form.methods.editRecord(
        JSON.stringify(this.selected, undefined, 4)
      );
```

this is the method in Form.vue

```
editRecord(modelEdit) {
  let self = this;
  self.model = modelEdit;
  console.log("model", self.model);
}
```

The model is filled correctly but the form is empty.

Just for test I have added one button inside Form.vue that calls this function(inside Form.vue):

```
testModel() {
  this.model = {
    "formField1": "Test1",
    "formField2": "Test2"
  }
  }
```

In that case it works, the form is filled with the data inside testModel().
But if I call this method from Table.vue it doesn't work.

The form is autogenerated from a json schema (I use vue-form-generator)

```
...
    <vue-form-generator :schema="schema" :model="model" :options="formOptions">
 ...   
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          model: {},
          schema: jsonschema,
    ...
```

I hope it is clear...Any hint?

Comment: Where did you get the `form` variable inside EditData?  Refer [Child Reference](https://012.vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Child_Reference) section for a hint on how to properly do this.

Comment: the form variable is retrieved in this way: import form from "@/components/myComponent/Form";

Comment: Child reference is not what I need. I am not in the case of parent-child but child -child